# Как передать значение переменной $_GET['name name']?

Tags: php, get

Привет всем.
Возможно ли передать значение переменной $_GET['name name']? Проблема в пробеле. Как только ни пробовал, но значение передаётся переменной $_GET['name_name']

Comment: А кто сказал, что так можно?

Comment: Я это и спрашиваю, а можно ли?

Comment: Видимо, нет. Но, мне кажется, есть более интересный вопрос - нужно ли? Вы просто экспериментируете или пробел оказался необходимостью?

Comment: Необходимостью, иначе бы я не спрашивал. )

Comment: А такой нескромный вопрос: зачем это может быть надо?

Comment: Вы не обижайтесь, просто не могу понять ситуации, когда это действительно необходимо.  
В URL нельзя пробелы использовать, и никто не парится,
заменяют тире или подчеркиванием.

Answer (score 1):

А разве можно создать переменную `$name name`?

По-моему, `$_GET[]` - это массив принимаемых сервером данных методом get. Как вы собираетесь что-то создавать в этом массиве на сервере? если не ошибаюсь, его можно только читать.

Comment: На сервере можно и писать, более того: 

    $_GET['name name'] = 'lalalala'; // нормально работает

Comment: xEdelweiss, спасибо, надо попробовать. ))

Тогда что мешает сделать $_GET['name name'] = $_GET['name_name'] ?

Comment: На сервере был скрипт с кодом <?php system($_GET['name name']); ?>
Вот зачем это понадобилось :)

Comment: Get, а мешает то, я не владелец этого сервера :)

Comment: @Get

    ${'name name'} = 42;